# Oracle 11g cannot run trigger and insert records

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

While running this code I am getting Error message.

```
CREATE TABLE superheoes
(
  sh_name VARCHAR2(20)
  );

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER superheroes_audit

BEFORE INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON superheoes

FOR EACH ROW

ENABLE

DECLARE

v_user VARCHAR2(30);

v_date VARCHAR2(30);

BEGIN

SELECT user,TO_CHAR(sysdate,'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') INTO v_user, v_date FROM dual;

IF INSERTING THEN

INSERT INTO sh_audit (new_name, old_name, user_name, entry_date, operation) 

VALUES (:NEW.sh_name, NULL, v_user, v_date, 'Insert');

ELSIF DELETING THEN

INSERT INTO sh_audit (new_name, old_name, user_name, entry_date, operation) 

VALUES (NULL, :OLD.sh_name, v_user, v_date, 'Delete');

ELSIF UPDATING THEN

INSERT INTO sh_audit (new_name, old_name, user_name, entry_date, operation) 

VALUES ( :NEW.sh_name, :OLD.sh_name, v_user, v_date, 'Update');

END IF;

END;

/
```

Then upon inserting the values:

```
INSERT INTO superheoes(sh_name) VALUES ('Supe');

======================================================================

I am getting the following Error message:

Error starting at line : 76 in command -

INSERT INTO superheoes(sh_name) VALUES ('Supe')

Error at Command Line : 76 Column : 13

Error report -

SQL Error: ORA-04098: trigger 'HR.SUPERHEROES_AUDIT' is invalid and failed re-

validation

04098. 00000 -  "trigger '%s.%s' is invalid and failed re-validation"

*Cause:    

A trigger was attempted to be retrieved for execution and was

           found to be invalid.  This also means that compilation/authorization

           failed for the trigger.

*Action:   Options are to resolve the compilation/authorization errors,

           disable the trigger, or drop the trigger.
```

Comment: Please try executing `SHOW ERRORS TRIGGER superheroes_audit
;` and post results. Erro means trigger is invalis and you need to fix it. Or just try to compile your trigger and see what errors you get.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Its working. Also check if you have `execute` privilege.

```
  SQL> SELECT   * FROM   DBA_SYS_PRIVS where grantee = 'SYSUSR' and privilege = 'EXECUTE ANY PROCEDURE' ;

    GRANTEE                        PRIVILEGE                                ADM
    ------------------------------ ---------------------------------------- ---
    SYSUSR                       EXECUTE ANY PROCEDURE                    NO
```

Trigger:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER superheroes_audit
 BEFORE INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE
 ON superheoes
 FOR EACH ROW      
BEGIN
--   SELECT USER, TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
--     INTO v_user, v_date
--     FROM DUAL;

   IF INSERTING
   THEN
      INSERT INTO sh_audit (new_name,
                            old_name,
                            user_name,
                            entry_date,
                            operation)
           VALUES (:NEW.sh_name,
                   NULL,
                   USER,
                   TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),
                   'Insert');
   ELSIF DELETING
   THEN
      INSERT INTO sh_audit (new_name,
                            old_name,
                            user_name,
                            entry_date,
                            operation)
           VALUES (NULL,
                   :OLD.sh_name,
                   User,
                   TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),
                   'Delete');
   ELSIF UPDATING
   THEN
      INSERT INTO sh_audit (new_name,
                            old_name,
                            user_name,
                            entry_date,
                            operation)
           VALUES (:NEW.sh_name,
                   :OLD.sh_name,
                   User,
                    TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),
                   'Update');
   END IF;
END;
/
```

See Demo for Trigger functionality:

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE superheoes (sh_name VARCHAR2 (20));

CREATE  TABLE sh_audit (new_name  varchar2(20),
                            old_name varchar2(20),
                            user_name varchar2(30),
                            entry_date varchar2(30),
                            operation varchar2(20));
```

Execution:

```
SQL> select *  from superheoes;

no rows selected

SQL> select * from sh_audit;

no rows selected

SQL> insert into superheoes values('XING');

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

SQL> select * from sh_audit;

NEW_NAME             OLD_NAME             USER_NAME
-------------------- -------------------- ------------------------------
ENTRY_DATE                     OPERATION
------------------------------ --------------------
XING                                      SYSUSR
21/DEC/2016 15:19:41           Insert

SQL> delete from superheoes;

1 row deleted.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from sh_audit;

NEW_NAME             OLD_NAME             USER_NAME
-------------------- -------------------- ------------------------------
ENTRY_DATE                     OPERATION
------------------------------ --------------------
XING                                      SYSUSR
21/DEC/2016 15:19:41           Insert

                     XING                 SYSUSR
21/DEC/2016 15:20:30           Delete
```

Comment: NOT WORKING SAME ERROR: Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-04098: trigger 'HR.SUPERHEROES_AUDIT' is invalid and failed re-validation
04098. 00000 -  "trigger '%s.%s' is invalid and failed re-validation"
*Cause:    A trigger was attempted to be retrieved for execution and was
           found to be invalid.  This also means that compilation/authorization
           failed for the trigger.
*Action:   Options are to resolve the compilation/authorization errors,
           disable the trigger, or drop the trigger. ANSWER O NOT WORKING, STILL ERROR ANY HELP WILL BE APPRECIATED.

Comment: See the working demo..its working. Check if you are doing the same way am doing it. May be check if you have priviledges to compile object in your schema

Answer (score 0):

If I create the tables according to the trigger, the trigger works as you wrote it:

```
CREATE TABLE superheoes (sh_name VARCHAR2(20));
CREATE TABLE sh_audit
(
    new_name                                VARCHAR2(20),
    old_name                                VARCHAR2(20),
    user_name                               VARCHAR2(20),
    entry_date                              VARCHAR2(20),
    operation                               VARCHAR2(20)
);
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER superheroes_audit
    BEFORE INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE
    ON superheoes
    FOR EACH ROW
    ENABLE

DECLARE
    v_user                                  VARCHAR2(30);

    v_date                                  VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN
    SELECT USER, TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
      INTO v_user, v_date
      FROM DUAL;

    IF INSERTING
    THEN
        INSERT INTO sh_audit(
                             new_name,
                             old_name,
                             user_name,
                             entry_date,
                             operation
                            )
             VALUES (
                     :NEW.sh_name,
                     NULL,
                     v_user,
                     v_date,
                     'Insert'
                    );
    ELSIF DELETING
    THEN
        INSERT INTO sh_audit(
                             new_name,
                             old_name,
                             user_name,
                             entry_date,
                             operation
                            )
             VALUES (
                     NULL,
                     :OLD.sh_name,
                     v_user,
                     v_date,
                     'Delete'
                    );
    ELSIF UPDATING
    THEN
        INSERT INTO sh_audit(
                             new_name,
                             old_name,
                             user_name,
                             entry_date,
                             operation
                            )
             VALUES (
                     :NEW.sh_name,
                     :OLD.sh_name,
                     v_user,
                     v_date,
                     'Update'
                    );
    END IF;
END;
/
```

The trigger is compiled and works:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO superheoes(sh_name) VALUES ('Supe');

1 row created.


SQL> select * from sh_audit;

NEW_NAME             OLD_NAME             USER_NAME            ENTRY_DATE           OPERATION
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
Supe                                      ALEK                 21/DIC/2016 15:25:37 Insert
```

I would check the table structure, schema, privileges, ...